# Regex to capture a variable number of items?

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to use a regex to capture values from SPACE delimited items. Yes, I know that I could use `[string]::Split()` or `-split`. The goal is to use a regex in order fit it into the regex of another, larger regex.

There are a variable number of items in the string. In this example there are four (4). The resulting $Matches variable has the full string for all Value members. I also tried the regex `'^((.*)\s*)+'`, but that resulted in '' for all except the first .\value.txt

How can I write a regex to capture a variable number of items.

```
PS C:\src\t> $s = 'now is the time'
PS C:\src\t> $m = [regex]::Matches($s, '^((.*)\s*)')
PS C:\src\t> $m

Groups    : {0, 1, 2}
Success   : True
Name      : 0
Captures  : {0}
Index     : 0
Length    : 15
Value     : now is the time
ValueSpan :

PS C:\src\t> $m.Groups.Value
now is the time
now is the time
now is the time
PS C:\src\t> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.2
```

Comment: Mathias' answer fixes the problem with your regex, but you can still use `[regex]::Matches()`:  `[regex]::Matches('now is the time', '\S+').Groups.Value`

Comment: @mklement0 There is a case to be made for `NextMatch()` over `Matches()` when the input string might contain _many_ matching substrings and the pattern contains many assertions, and you're only interested in results up to a certain point/threshold - in that case, only consuming one match at a time might reduce the state complexity of the underlying regex runner and save you some memory and/or time. (Although with the given example there's no real benefit :) )

Comment: That makes sense, @Mathias, but given how the question is formulated I wouldn't _lead_ with that solution (and, either way, including an explanation such as you just gave would be helpful). I suggest leading with `[regex]::Matches()` (at which point I'd be happy to up-vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[regex]::Match()` to find the *first* matching substring, then call `NextMatch()` to advance through the input string until no further matches can be made.

I've taken the liberty of simplifying the expression to `\S+` (consecutive non-whitespace characters):

```
$string = 'now is the time'
$regex = [regex]'\S+'

$match = $regex.Match($string)
while($match.Success){
  Write-Host "Match at index [$($match.Index)]: '$($match.Value)'"

  # advance to the next match, if any
  $match = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

Which will print:

```
Match at index [0]: 'now'
Match at index [4]: 'is'
Match at index [7]: 'the'
Match at index [11]: 'time'
```

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. This does work. Although I do not know how I could integrate it into the larger regex problem. If I do not figure something else out, I will ask another question.

Comment: What larger regex problem? Sounds intriguing :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, the larger regex needs to pick out the words between the STORE_NUM and MARK text. `$m = [regex]::Matches('west 123 now is the time MARK blah blah blah', '^(.*)\s+(\d*)\s+((\S+)\s+)*MARK.*')`

Answer (score 0):

[Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71653086/45375) shows an *iterative* approach to retrieving all matches, which may or may not be needed.

Building on your own attempt to use [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches), the solution is as simple as:

```bash
$s = 'now is the time'
[regex]::Matches($s, '\S+').Value # -> @('now', 'is', 'the', 'time')
```

As noted, `\S+` matches any non-empty run (`+`) of *non*-whitespace characters (`\S`).

Thanks to [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), accessing the `.Value` property on the method call's result, which is a collection of [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match) instances, each instance's `.Value` property is returned, which in the case of two or more instances results in an *array* of values.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the following will work for you

```
[^\s]+
```

`[^\s]` means "not a space"

`+` means 1 or more characters

Comment: Are you suggesting that `$m = [regex]::Matches('now is the time', '[^s]+')` would work? It does not seem to for me?

Comment: @lit, you're missing a ``\`` before `s` in your command, but otherwise, yes, this would work (but can be simplified to `\S+`).